# Using parameters in ngUpload

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the directive ngUpload for file uploading. https://github.com/twilson63/ngUpload

I need some parameters in my restcall.

I tried the following.

```
  <form id="foo" ng-upload="uploadComplete(content)" method="post" action="api/resources?pr_id={{projectId}}">
```

But in the console i get an error in my console:

```
Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] Error while interpolating: api/resources?pr_id={{projectId}}
Strict Contextual Escaping disallows interpolations that concatenate multiple expressions when a trusted value is required.  See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce
```

I read the ng.$sce but I don't get it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem as well.  My solution was to create a custom angular directive call ngAction.

```
angular.module('yourApp').directive('ngAction', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) { elem.attr('action', attrs.ngAction) }
  }
})
```

So your form tag would look like this:

```
<form id="foo" ng-upload="uploadComplete(content)" method="post" ng-action="api/resources?pr_id={{projectId}}">
```

Hope this helps out.